# fnmatches fails to match '?' to zero occurences

Tags: c, wildcard, fnmatch

I'm writing a basic test for fnmatch before integrating in my code. Here is the test:

```c
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
        if (!fnmatch(argv[1], argv[i], 0))
            printf("%s matches %s\n", argv[i], argv[1]);
        else
            printf("%s doesn't matches %s\n", argv[i], argv[1]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled it to `test` and run the following command:

```sh
$ ./test a*b? a ab aa acb abc aabc acbc aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba abb aabb
```

Expexted output:

```
a doesn't matches a*b?
ab matches a*b?
aa doesn't matches a*b?
acb matches a*b?
abc matches a*b?
aabc matches a*b?
acbc matches a*b?
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba matches a*b?
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab matches a*b?
abb matches a*b?
aabb matches a*b?
```

Real output:

```
a doesn't matches a*b?
ab doesn't matches a*b?
aa doesn't matches a*b?
acb doesn't matches a*b?
abc matches a*b?
aabc matches a*b?
acbc matches a*b?
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab doesn't matches a*b?
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba matches a*b?
abb matches a*b?
aabb matches a*b?
```

The problem being that the '?' metacharacter fails to match 0 characters (requiring exactly one).

Does anyone know why is it behaving this way and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to match 0 or 1 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Posix glob matches `?` to a single character, not an empty group. See [glob matching](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

`?` can be used to match empty group in regular expressions, though - where it does match zero or one occurrence.

Comment: Can fnmatch handle regex matching?

Comment: That is implementation-dependent. You cannot assume it.

Comment: `Can fnmatch handle regex matching?` No, regex is not glob.

Comment: In this case, is there a flag to pass to fnamtch to get it to behave as desired? Or another c function that behaves in the same way?

Comment: @Moh you can use `regcomp()` and `regexec()` for regular expressions, or a more featureful third party library like pcre2.

Comment: @Moh For Posix, you can use their Regex implementation, documentation can be found here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html

Answer (score 2):

If using a Linux OS with the glibc implementation of `fnmatch()`, you can use the `FNM_EXTMATCH` flag to enable `ksh`/`bash` style extended globbing, where `?(pattern)` matches *pattern* 1 or 0 times. Using that, `?(?)` will match 1 or 0 instances of any character.

Example:

```c
// Define before any includes to get FNM_EXTMATCH
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
        if (fnmatch(argv[1], argv[i], FNM_EXTMATCH) == 0)
            printf("%s matches %s\n", argv[i], argv[1]);
        else
            printf("%s doesn't match %s\n", argv[i], argv[1]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And usage (Tip: Put the pattern in quotes to prevent your shell from trying to expand it):

```
$ ./test  "a*b?(?)" a ab aa acb abc aabc acbc aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba abb aabb
a doesn't match a*b?(?)
ab matches a*b?(?)
aa doesn't match a*b?(?)
acb matches a*b?(?)
abc matches a*b?(?)
aabc matches a*b?(?)
acbc matches a*b?(?)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab matches a*b?(?)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba matches a*b?(?)
abb matches a*b?(?)
aabb matches a*b?(?)
```